# How to redirect js,css files to folder?

Tags: .htaccess

But except of api folder and index.html file?
my folder:

```
api/
dist/
index.html
```

all css and js files in dist folder
how to redirect all file requests to dist folder?

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)$ /dist/$ [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use these rules:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(?!dist/|api/).*$ dist/$0 [NC,L]
```